# Generate Integer Random Numbers in Python Array

Tags: python, arrays, random

I'm trying to make an array with 30 integer elements between 0 and 2 randomly chosen. When some number is chosen 10 times, i can't append it anymore. In the end, I need an array with 30 elements with 10 numbers 0, 10 numbers 1 and 10 numbers 2. Here's what i'm trying:

```
import random
array_size = 30
number = 3
counter = [0, 0, 0]
solution = []

for i in range(array_size):
    number = random.randrange(number) #generates numbers between 0 and 2

    while counter[number] > 10:
        number = random.randrange(number)

    counter[number] += 1
    solution.append(number)
```

As result, i have more than 10 elements of the same number. I believe the problem is in the random number that i put in the while is not changed even if i change it inside the loop. Someone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `random.shuffle([0]*10 + [1]*10 + [2]*10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
while number[counter] > 10:
```

to

```
while number[counter] >= 10:
```

Originally your code would only stop appending a certain number only if there were more than 10 instances of it within your array. By changing it to a >=, the program will stop appending the number the moment it adds it for a tenth time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
import random

number = 3
size = 30

steps = math.ceil(size / number)

solution = []
for x in range(steps):
    for n in range(number):
        solution.append(n)

random.shuffle(solution)
print(solution)
```